# Remove file paths from TEXT directives in go binaries

Tags: go, elf

I want to **remove** all path information like `/Users/myuser/dev/go/src/fooapi/spikes/mongoapi.go` from the executable that I created with `go build`.

**I'm compiling the code like this:**

`CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -v -a -ldflags="-w -s" -o ./fooapi spikes/mongoapi.go`

**Some part of the example assembly from the go build command above:**

```
$ go tool objdump ./fooapi
.
.
TEXT main.init(SB) /Users/myuser/dev/go/src/api/spikes/mongoapi.go
mongoapi.go:60  0x12768c0   65488b0c25a0080000  GS MOVQ GS:0x8a0, CX
mongoapi.go:60  0x12768c9   483b6110        CMPQ 0x10(CX), SP
mongoapi.go:60  0x12768cd   7663            JBE 0x1276932
.
.
```

---

Note that: `strip` is not recommended and [can lead to broken executables](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=717172) if you're going to recommend it as a solution.

Comment: BTW, that issue about strip is very old, and no longer relevant. The generally accepted solution for _any_ toolchain is to build the executable in a temporary or generic build path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Use -trimpath flags to remove path information:**

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -v -a -ldflags="-w -s" \
    -gcflags=-trimpath=/Users/myuser/dev/go/src \
    -asmflags=-trimpath=/Users/myuser/dev/go/src \
    -o ./fooapi spikes/mongoapi.go
```

---

**More Information:**

Passing `-trimpath` to `-gcflags` and `-asmflags` will remove any path information from the elf binary.

```
$ go tool asm -help 2>&1 | grep -A1 trimpath
-trimpath string
    remove prefix from recorded source file paths

$ go tool compile -help|grep -A1 trimpath
-trimpath string
    remove prefix from recorded source file paths
```

**You can check the result with `go tool objdump`:**

```
$ go tool objdump ./fooapi
.
.
TEXT main.init(SB) api/spikes/mongoapi.go
mongoapi.go:60  0x12768c0   65488b0c25a0080000  GS MOVQ GS:0x8a0, CX
mongoapi.go:60  0x12768c9   483b6110        CMPQ 0x10(CX), SP
mongoapi.go:60  0x12768cd   7663            JBE 0x1276932
.
.
```

---

Using `strip` tool has still some controversies in go community, although it's been said that it's been fixed. Some say that unknown and unpredictable bugs occur sometimes. Read [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/2a95488f7843a773de2b541a47d9b971a635bfff/project/PACKAGERS.md#stripping-binaries) and [here](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/20584/3) for examples.

Comment: I have been informed by Russ Cox that `-gcflags=-trimpath=...` and `-asmflags=-trimpath=...` are not officially supported and in fact they fail to fully remove the path from the binary. The correct parameter is just `-trimpath=...`.

Answer (score 9):

`trimpath` is a good approach, but had issues like [go issue 24976](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24976#issuecomment-439189276)

> It appears that, when multiple `-trimpath` flags are passed to go tool compile, the last one wins
>
> Indeed; from what I can tell the `trimpath` flag is defined as an ordinary string flag, not a list.

But with [CL 173344](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/173344/), this is now fixed (for the upcoming Go 1.13)

> ### cmd/internal/objabi: expand -trimpath syntax
>
> This CL affects the low-level `-trimpath` flag provided
>   by both `cmd/asm` and `cmd/compile`.
>
> Previously, the flag took the name of a single directory that would be trimmed
>   from recorded paths in the resulting object file.
>
> This CL **makes the flag take a semicolon-separated list of paths**.
>
> Further, each path can now end in an optional "`=>replacement`"
>   to specify what to replace that leading path prefix with,
>   instead of only dropping it.
>
> A followup CL will add a mode to `cmd/go` that uses this
>   richer `-trimpath` to build binaries that do not contain any
>   local path names.

This is [CL 173345](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/173345/):

> ### `cmd/go`: add `-trimpath` build flag
>
> "`go build -trimpath`" trims the recorded file paths in the resulting packages and executables to avoid recording the names of any local directories.
>   Instead, the files appear to be stored in directories named either "`go/src/...`" (for the standard library) or named after the module or package in which the files appear.

This fixes [issue 16860](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16860), which is about Go ability to  generate bit-for-bit identical binaries, as noted by [**Ivan Daniluk**](https://twitter.com/idanyliuk/status/1123512636795236352).

Answer (score -1):

This is for anyone using a version of go that does NOT support the -trimpath build option...

I have to use version 1.10.8.  My project has multiple packages. The trick to removing the file path for ALL the packages (not just main) from the executable is to use the package pattern "all" with -gcflags:

```
go1.10.8 build -gcflags=all=-trimpath=%GOPATH%
```