# golang runtime package sets filepaths from the system on which it was built

Tags: go, runtime, elf, gopath

I've a simple go code, that uses the **runtime** package as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "fmt"
)

func bar() {
    pc := make([]uintptr, 1000)
    n := runtime.Callers(0, pc)
    frames := runtime.CallersFrames(pc[:n])
    for {
        frame, more := frames.Next()
        if ! more {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("FILE = %s and FUNC = %s\n", frame.File, frame.Function)
    }
}

func foo() {
    bar()
}

func main() {
    foo()
}
```

I've Go binary installed in a custom location (/home/**userA**/bin/go) on a Ubuntu machine (say **machine A**)

I've compiled it on machine **A** and ran the executable on the same machine to get the output:

```
FILE = /home/userA/bin/go/src/runtime/extern.go and FUNC = runtime.Callers
FILE = /home/userA/src/main.go and FUNC = main.bar
FILE = /home/userA/src/main.go and FUNC = main.foo
FILE = /home/userA/src/main.go and FUNC = main.main
FILE = /home/userA/bin/go/src/runtime/proc.go and FUNC = runtime.main
```

Now I copied the compiled executable to another Ubuntu machine (say **machine B**) where Go binary was installed in another different custom location (/home/**userB**/bin/go). I ran the executable from **/home/userB**. But this time also, I got the same output as before:

```
FILE = /home/userA/bin/go/src/runtime/extern.go and FUNC = runtime.Callers
FILE = /home/userA/src/main.go and FUNC = main.bar
FILE = /home/userA/src/main.go and FUNC = main.foo
FILE = /home/userA/src/main.go and FUNC = main.main
FILE = /home/userA/bin/go/src/runtime/proc.go and FUNC = runtime.main
```

It seems that the **runtime** package sets the stack-frames during compilation time.

I need to do some processing on the file paths based on **GOPATH** environment variable, which I've set as **/home/userA** on machine **A** and as **/home/userB** on machine **B**.

I need to strip the GOPATH part from each of those file paths. I'm doing it with this simple function call: `strings.Replace(frame.File, GOPATH, "", 1)`

But, because of this behaviour of the runtime package, the `strings.Replace` function fails to replace the initial portion of the file paths on machine **B**.

Any idea on how to accomplish this on machine **B** ?

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion from @JimB, I've built the project with

`CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -ldflags="-w -s" -gcflags=-trimpath=/home/userA -asmflags=-trimpath=/home/userA`

Now, running the executable on the same machine gives output as:

```
FILE = /home/userA/bin/go/src/runtime/extern.go and FUNC = runtime.Callers
FILE = /home/userA/src/vendor/github.com/kataras/golog/golog.go and FUNC = vendor/github.com/kataras/golog.Error
FILE = /home/userA/src/test/test_logger.go and FUNC = test/test_logger.TestLogger
FILE = src/main.go and FUNC = main.bar
FILE = src/main.go and FUNC = main.foo
FILE = src/main.go and FUNC = main.main
FILE = /home/userA/bin/go/src/runtime/proc.go and FUNC = runtime.main
```

The path prefix is trimmed only for the main file. It's still there for any vendor imported package or any locally imported package.

Comment: Are you just trying to manually implement this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279385/remove-file-paths-from-text-directives-in-go-binaries

Comment: You probably want `runtime.GOROOT`

Comment: @MichaelHampton, using `runtime.GOROOT` doesn't solve my problem. Actually I'll compile the code on machine **A**, where golang will be installed in some custom location as `/home/userA`, but I'll run the executable on some machine where go will be installed in its standard location like `/usr/bin`. So, using `GOROOT`, I won't be able to replace the prefix successfully.

Comment: @JimB your solution works but only for a single file, not for any imported packages (both from my project and from any 3rd party vendor). I've updated the post with the situation.